# How to get the probability of a particular token(word) in a sentence given the context

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm trying to calculate the probability or any type of score for words in a sentence using NLP. I've tried this approach with GPT2 model using Huggingface Transformers library, but, I couldn't get satisfactory results due to the model's unidirectional nature which for me didn't seem to predict within context. So I was wondering whether there is a way, to calculate the above said using BERT since it's Bidirectional.

I've found this [post](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/473#issuecomment-482674742) relatable, which I randomly saw the other day but didn't see any answer which would be useful for me as well.

Hope I will be able to receive ideas or a solution for this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

BERT is trained as a masked language model, i.e., it is trained to predict tokens that were replaced by a `[MASK]` token.

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM

tok = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
bert = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

input_idx = tok.encode(f"The {tok.mask_token} were the best rock band ever.")
logits = bert(torch.tensor([input_idx]))[0]
prediction = logits[0].argmax(dim=1)
print(tok.convert_ids_to_tokens(prediction[2].numpy().tolist()))
```

It prints token no. 11581 which is:

> Beatles

To get a normalized probability distribution over BERT's vocabulary, you can normalize the logits using the [softmax function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.softmax.html), i.e., `F.softmax(logits, dim=1)`, (assuming standart `import torch.nn.fucntional as F`).

The tricky thing is that words might be split into multiple subwords. You can simulate that by adding multiple `[MASK]` tokens, but then you have a problem with how to compare the scores of prediction so different lengths reliably. I would probably average the probabilities, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering whether I can predict the positions to place [MASK] tokens in a corrupted sentence depending on the probability of  words so that the [MASK] tokens can be predicted using masked language modelling in order to get a proper clean grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: @D.Perera you may find [this](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W19-4412/) work interesting. You just need to have a vast space of alternative edits and then use the model given probabilities with greedy search to choose the best edit.

Comment: This "answer" does not give you the probability P(word | context) but rather it predicts the most likely word. This is not what the question is asking for.

Comment: @toom is it clearer now after the recent edit? The point of the question is the difference between GPT-2 and BERT (which is in the `[MASK]` tokens), normalizing logits using softmax is the same in both models, so I thought there was no need to mention that.

Comment: Well, maybe my knowledge about the application of BERT is insufficient. I will have to try this out on my own and see what happens. In the meantime you should forget about what I have written here :P

Anyway, thanks for your answer :)